# xcode/Firebase fails to create user on Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication

I'm new to Xcode and firebase.
I made this simple email login just to check if it works, but it doesn´t.

Firebase is set to public. And I can read and write data.
Now, when working authentication, do I need to change anything?
It doesn't display any errors, it just doesn't create any users in Firebase.

The code is:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var Username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Password: UITextField!

    @IBAction func Register(_ sender: UIButton) {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: Username.text!, password: Password.text!) { (User, Error) in

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you imported your google plist to your project?

Comment: Log the `Error` value in the completion handler.

Comment: FYI - In Swift it is standard to start variable and methods names with lowercase letters. Class and struct names start with uppercase letters.

Comment: I have added the plist yes, and there isn't any error rmaddy. It simply won't add any user to the firebase authentication. Nothing seems wrong, beside the part that it won't be shown in Firebase. And thanks for the info, rmaddy, will fix it in my code.

Comment: I think you only have authenticated the user , now you need to update the child values in the db , only then you will see the data in firebase

Comment: Have you initialized the `Auth` before your call? and try to print `User` in case you get the user object and also check whether you pass a valid email formatted text.

Comment: @3stud1ant3, he is talking about firebase authentication not firebase database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the problem.
We thought we could use a username instead of an email, but it needs to be an email.

Comment: Who is "we"? This isn't your question. And don't post questions as an answer.

Comment: Are you asking about "Firebase Phone Auth"? 
Be clear and please post your own question don't put question on answers fields.

Comment: Sry, we is me and the one who posted this question. The answer to his question is that it had to be an email and not just a sale number or something.

Im asking how can we use something like a sale number as a username?

Comment: @JonasLarsen, I've already commented on it the same thing. Please check it and there are possible type of firebase auth. Please go through this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/)